# After Adding WatchKit Target it's Files Turns Red

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch, xcasset

I started a new project in `xCode 6.3` then I Selected `File > New > Target > AppleWatch` and after the confirmation dialogue I got this: 
 [image: Red Files in WatchKit App and Extension] Why is this happening?
 **UPDATE:**
When I clicked on the project it gave me this message:
[image: The folder “Images.xcassets” doesn’t exist.]

Comment: i have the same issue, have you got it done :)

Comment: i just found it will NOT happen on Xcode6.2

Comment: If you move your say `InterfaceController.m` file from `WetRide WatchKit Extension` folder to your project foler `WetRide` and then move it back it'll not be red :D
Actually one of my seniors solved this issue for me he did something in the `.plist` where you give address of `xcasset` folder etc.

Comment: this bug has been fixed in 6.3.1 :)

Comment: @Jacky Question solved :D

Comment: @Jacky It still happens in 6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solve it by first select your `WatchKit Extension` folder, in file inspector, click the folder icon in bottom right, then select the right folder in popped window.

Finally do the same thing to `WatchKit App` folder:)

[image]